# Spring MVC views don't seem to be working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having a bit of trouble to map the views in a simple Spring MVC beginner tutorial, and I keep getting the same error which is:

> 22:18:30.700 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web_spring/Candidate-module/getCandidate] in DispatcherServlet with name 'webmvc-dispatcher'

I have messed around with the names trying to get them to work but that wasn't the problem. I will post the code and any help would be greatly appreciated!

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>web_spring</display-name>


<servlet>
 <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


 <context:component-scan base-package="ie.cit.oossp" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>



</beans>
```

CandidateController.java

```
package web_spring.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import web_spring.beans.Candidate;
import web_spring.service.CandidateService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Candidate-module")
public class CandidateController {


@Autowired
private CandidateService service;  

@RequestMapping(value = "/getCandidate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("msg", "Hello Spring Web App");
    return "vote";
}
}
```

vote.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Vote here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vote : ${msg}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your directory structure???

Answer (score 0):

Enable annotation driven MVC by adding following config to the `webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

This registers a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, and an `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` (among others) in support of processing requests with annotated controller methods using annotations such as `@RequestMapping`, `@ExceptionHandler`, and others.
So your config file would be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    // same as before
</beans>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, these are the 3 debug/warn messages I get off Tomcat

Comment: 22:45:04.455 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'webmvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/web_spring/Candidate-module/getCandidate]

Comment: 22:45:04.460 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web_spring/Candidate-module/getCandidate] in DispatcherServlet with name 'webmvc-dispatcher'

Comment: 22:45:04.461 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

Comment: You config file is `webmvc.xml` or `webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`?

Comment: It is webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Are you sure you're deploying this to tomcat under `web_spring` context? Whats your war file name?